# preg_replace() <Char /> tags

Tags: php, regex, tags, preg-replace

I have this xml:

```
<RandomAlphaCharsA attr1="value1" attr2="value2 attrX="valueX" />
<RandomAlphaCharsB attr1="value1" attr2="value2 attrX="valueX" />
```

I need to strip the following:

`<RandomAlphaCharsX` and `/>`, preserving only the attributes/values.

I tried this pattern:

```
$str = '<RandomAlphaChars attr1="value1" attr2="value2 attrX="valueX" />';

$str = preg_replace( "#<\w+[\s]{1}#", "", $str, -1 );`
var_dump( $str );

//it echoes string(46) "attr1="value1" attr2="value2 attrX="valueX" />"
```

This pattern in the other hand matches the closing tag:

```
preg_replace("#/>#", "", $str, -1);
```

How can I put them together in a single regexp?

Obviously, this is not working `preg_replace("#<\w+[\s]{1}/>#", "", $str, -1);`

I need to somehow exclude all kind of characters between `<RandomAlphaChars` and `/>` and I need some help with that.

**Edit:** Wow you are fast. All answers work great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<\S+|\/>
```

This should match both.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/nW4yD9/1

Answer (score 1):

Join them with the or operator `|` :

```
$str = preg_replace( "#<\w+\s+|\s+/>#", "", $str);`
```

Comment: You have a backtick (`) in your code what will cause PHP fatal error :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's mine:

```
$str = preg_replace('#<\w+\s+(.*?)\s*/>#s', '$1', $str);
```